# Unity3D Facebook FB.AppRequest doesn't work on android

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm trying to send App Requests from my game (made with Unity3D) using the official facebook plugin.
I can login, post on wall and use graph api without problems, so I know that I'm on the right way, but when I try to send App Request the callback functions seems to never been called on my android phone.
On unity3d player instead I get this error log:

```
400 Bad Request
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
FbDebug:Error(String)
Facebook.FallbackData:JSFallback(String)
Facebook.AsyncRequestDialogPost:CallbackWithErrorHandling(FBResult)
Facebook.<Start>c__Iterator0:MoveNext()
```

I'm trying to send app requests with this code:

```
FB.AppRequest(
                message: "Hi! I'm playing Grave Run for Android! Download it from Google Play :)",
                title: "Play Grave Run with me!",
                callback: RequestCallback);
```

Maybe I'm missing some permissions ?? here is how I login:

```
FB.Login("read_friendlists,publish_actions", LoginCallback);
```

Many thanks for the help !

Comment: What do you see in the logcat for android?

Comment: I haven't debugged with logcat, since I've used the unity3d debug.log messages to try to find the reason of this issue. If needed I can try to logcat, just let me know..

Comment: I've used logcat, here is the log: http://pastebin.com/XjgyM4qL

Comment: Your logcat seems fine.  May I ask which SDK version you are using?  Also what is RequestCallback doing?

Comment: Hi briank, I'm using the latest facebook sdk (ver. 4.3.6), the RequestCallback should just debug.log the fbresult message.. Any idea ?

Comment: Is the Unity Development Build enabled when you built this?
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PublishingBuilds.html

Debug messages done with `Debug.Log` won't show up otherwise.

Comment: No mate I used an external tool to read Debug.Log messages on my device. By the way the callback function is never called as I've said. Everything works ok, I can select the firends that should receive the invite, but then them doesn't receive it..

Comment: UPDATE!! Brian, if I go here: https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/requests while logged with my friend's account, I can see the requests number increasing every time I invite this friend, but the request is not present in the list :(

Comment: UPDATE2!! Brian, I was able to found my request in that page! I was not displayed due to the great ammount of requests.. by the way, why it doesn't appear in the notification bar ?? Many thanks for the help

Comment: Even if you use an external tool (I'm guessing adb), Unity won't add `Debug.Log` statements to your game unless you check the "Unity Development Build".  It's just a check to do a debug build instead of a release build of your game.  I'm asking if that checkbox is checked.

Comment: No it is not checked but I can still read the debug.log using a 3rd part tool called KGFDebugger..

Comment: Could you try checking the field and rebuilding it?  I just want to eliminate it as a possibility.

Comment: Now I can see "Development Build" on my game..

Comment: And there's still no messages from your `Debug.Log` in the `RequestCallback`?